# Java String.equals() method doesn't return true or false

Tags: java, android

I have the following code running on Android that compares two strings and returns the object field, if its `variable` is equal to `id`.

The values are never `null`, and there's one case when I have `id = "m1"` and `var = "m1"`. (`getFields()` retrieves the fields from a MongoDB database.)

By watching the expression `var.equal(id)`on debug mode, I see it returns `true`, but it doesn't go into either one of the `if`s below (it does enter the loop.) What is going on here?

```
public Field getField(String id) {
    for (Field field : getFields()) {
        String var = field.getProperties().getVariable();

        // I know I'm not supposed to do like this.
        // This is just for debug purposes.
        if (!var.equals(id)) {
            // Doesn't get into here
            Log.d("Different?", "Yes.");
        }

        if (var.equals(id)) {
            // Doesn't get into here either
            return field;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Does it enter the loop at all? Does an Exception short-circuit your code?

Comment: Of course String.equals returns true or false - and, for the same input, String.equals will produce the same output. Now, while holding this premise, continue to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Pass the result to a `boolean` variable and print it out. It can only be one or the other. Alternatively, your debugger is broken.

Comment: why are you checking the same string twice? Use `if/else` here.

Comment: @KevinWorkman it enters the loops, and I just surrounded it by a try-catch. There's no exception.

Answer (score 0):

tldr; The diagnoses is incorrect and should be reevaluated. It isn't unheard of for a debugger to report misleading information (or even introduce side-effects), but the actual Dalvik run-time/classes have well-defined behavior.

For any given strings (where null is not a string), represented by x and y, it is always the case that `x.equals(y)` == `y.equals(x)` and the output is [deterministic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_algorithm) based *only* on the two input strings<sup>1</sup>.

While it is *better* to use if/else, by the deterministic nature of the equals (and usage of such in the provided code), the following semantic equivalency holds:

```
if (x.equals(y)) { a; }
else { b; }
// -- and --
if (x.equals(y)) { a; }
if (!x.equals(y)) { b; }
```

That is, *exactly one* of {a, b} must execute - *iff* that code runs at all and no exceptions are thrown.

---

<sup>1</sup> The only way this can differ is if the variables are reassigned between the calls; since they are both local variables then there is no potential threading issue. Because strings are [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) it is also guaranteed that there is no way to change the result of the String.equals function, provided the same string objects are supplied.

> [String.equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) compares this string to the specified object. The result is true if and only if the argument .. represents the same sequence of characters as this object.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is better written as:

```
public Field getField(final String id) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    for (Field field : getFields()) {
        String var = field.getProperties().getVariable();

        if (var.equals(id)) {
            // match found
            return field;
        } else {
            // no match
            Log.d("Different?", "Yes.");
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No match for " + id + " found!");
}
```

It appears maybe your `id` is not really included in `getFields()` return, and/or it's in a different case than you expect.

You could try:

```
if (var.equalsIgnoreCase(id))
```

This will check for upper and lower case values.

And if you are returning `null` (from your original method) or catching the `IllegalArgumentException` from my re-write, then this means no match was found, ie. your `id` is not really included in the return from `getFields()`.

For debugging you can print all of the returned fields:

```
for (Field field : getFields()) {
    System.out.println(field.getProperties().getVariable());
    // do your stuff

}
```

Another debug option:

```
public Field getField(final String id) throws IllegalArgumentException {

    Field[] fields = getFields();
    System.out.println("How many fields? " + fields.length);

    for (Field field : getFields()) {
        String var = field.getProperties().getVariable();

        System.out.println("Variable var is: " + var);
        System.out.println("Variable id is: " + id);

        if (var.equals(id)) {
            // match found
            return field;
        } else {
            // no match
            Log.d("Different?", "Yes.");
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No match for " + id + " found!");
}
```

Comment: why ? returning null is a perfectly acceptable value. People don't want to be catching exception all the time.

Comment: @njzk2 you're serious? null checking is just as bad, if not worse. If he catches, then he knows immediately there was a problem, and what the problem was. ... not to mention i simplified his original logic.

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to write my code as I did. I've done that for debug purposes. Even when I use if/else, it jumps right to `return null`, and it doesn't throw any exception.

Comment: @AntonioJunior then I presume you don't know your data very well, ie. your `field` is not in the same case as the `id`, and/or it's not there at all. You can try using `var.equalsIgnoreCase(id)` then instead.

Comment: @SnakeDoc I know my data. I am executing the method using Eclipse debug, and I know that I'm not getting any `null` values anywhere. By the point the equals fails, it fails when comparing exactly equal values. I checked, the chars are equal, the bytes are equal. I believe the error is somewhere else here.

Comment: @AntonioJunior your code is pretty simple here. The issue is going to be either the data is not there, or is not equal. Otherwise it would do what you coded it to do. Perhaps the `field.getProperties().getVariable()` is not doing what you expect?

Comment: @AntonioJunior I just added some more debug options you can try.

Comment: @SnakeDoc : quite serious yes. `getField` returns a value if there is one to be found, or none if there is not. `null` seems quite appropriate for that. That's how `Map` works, and this case is quite similar.